# yaws_log message count is continue growing

Tags: erlang, yaws

I embedded YAWS in my application at production environment, and I found the yaws_log message count is continue growing (from 08/Dec/2016 ).
[image: messages]

Observer shows the yaws_log process Memory size is 2326160312, and the Message count is 799501
[image: observer]

The localhost:8081.access file size is 2.5Mb and the last log time is 08/Dec/2016:11:14:26, but today is 12/Dec/2016.

I also check the disk, but it is not full.

### Update

I'm using YAWS 2.0.4 and Erlang/OTP 19.1

Below are partial messages in the yaws_log process

```
Pid = whereis(yaws_log).
erlang:process_info(Pid, messages).
[{'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'GET',
           {abs_path,
               "/f/169bfcd4-cca5-472a-bda2-fff7f608eebc.jpg?type=4"},
           {1,1}},
       {headers,"close",undefined,"larzio.maxkit.com.tw:443",
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,[],undefined,
           undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,true,false,false,decide,191109,0,
           "Connection: close\r\n",
           ["Server: ","Yaws 2.0.4","\r\n"],
           undefined,undefined,undefined,
           ["Date: ",[...]|...],
           undefined,undefined,...},
       3515}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,[],undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,undefined,
           ["Server: ","Yaws 2.0.4","\r\n"],
           undefined,undefined,undefined,
           [[...]|...],
           [...],...},
       74}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'GET',
           {abs_path,
               "/f/169bfcd4-cca5-472a-bda2-fff7f608eebc.jpg?type=3"},
           {1,1}},
       {headers,"close",undefined,"larzio.maxkit.com.tw:443",
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,[],undefined,...},
       {outh,200,true,false,false,decide,13159,0,
           "Connection: close\r\n",
           ["Server: ","Yaws 2.0.4","\r\n"],
           undefined,undefined,undefined,
           [...],...},
       3450}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,[],...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,undefined,
           ["Server: ","Yaws 2.0.4",[...]],
           undefined,undefined,undefined,...},
       72}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,undefined,
           ["Server: ",[...]|...],
           undefined,undefined,...},
       69}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,undefined,
           [[...]|...],
           undefined,...},
       80}}},
 secs3,
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,undefined,...},
       82}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,0,...},
       71}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,0,...},
       87}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
           undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,identity,...},
       71}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,false,...},
       73}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{1,0}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,false,false,...},
       72}}},
 secs3,
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS','*',{...}},
       {headers,undefined,undefined,...},
       {outh,200,...},
       71}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,1},
       {http_request,'POST',{...},...},
       {headers,[...],...},
       {outh,...},
       1743}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,21}},
      {{127,0,0,...},
       {http_request,'OPTIONS',...},
       {headers,...},
       {...},...}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.1769762>,...}},
      {{127,0,...},{http_request,...},{...},...}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,{...}},
      {{127,...},{...},...}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,
      {file_descriptor,prim_file,...},
      {{...},...}}},
 {'$gen_cast',
     {"localhost:8081",access,{file_descriptor,...},{...}}},
 {'$gen_cast',{"localhost:8081",access,{...},...}},
 {'$gen_cast',{"localhost:8081",access,...}},
 secs3,
 {'$gen_cast',{...}},
 {'$gen_cast',...},
 {...}|...]}
```

Comment: Please provide the versions of Yaws and Erlang/OTP you're using.

Comment: Also, please double-click the `yaws_log` process and in the new window choose the Messages tab. What do the messages in the queue look like?

Comment: Please also provide the output of `process_info(whereis(yaws_log)).`

Comment: The message of yaws_log is growing to 1 million, and the service become unstable. So I restarted the server yesterday. I will continue watching the yaws_log process, and remember to execute `process_info(whereis(yaws_log))` , thank you.